# Install OpenCv 2.4.2 with Cuda on Visual studio 9 2008: errors in build

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cuda

I have been trying to install OpenCv 2.4.2 with cuda enabled on visual studio 9 2008.

These are the below specs:

OpenCv version: 2.4.2
OS: Windows 7 64 bit
Cmake version: 2.8.9
Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 550 Ti
Cuda version: 4.2

I downloaded the opencv from [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.2/OpenCV-2.4.2.exe/download) and have followed all the instructions correctly.

This is the result of the CMake configuration:

> GUI:
>  QT 4.x: NO   Win32 UI: YES
>   OpenGL support: NO
>   Media I/O:
>   ZLib: build (ver 1.2.6)
>    JPEG: build (ver
>         62)
>   PNG: build (ver 1.5.9)
>   TIFF: build (ver 42 -
>         4.0.1)
>   JPEG 2000: build (ver 1.900.1)
>   OpenEXR: NO 
>          Video I/O:
>  FFMPEG: YES (prebuilt binaries)
>  codec: YES(ver 53.61.100
>  format: YES (ver 53.32.100
>  util: YES(ver
>   51.35.100)
>  swscale: YES (ver 2.1.100)
>  gentoo-style:YES
>  OpenNI: NO 
>  OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules: NO
>  PvAPI: NO 
>   DirectShow: YES
>  XIMEA: NO
>
> Other third-party libraries Use IPP: NO 
>   Use TBB: NO 
>  Use
>   Cuda: YES (ver 4.2) 
>   Use Eigen: NO
>
> NVIDIA CUDA: (ver 4.2) 
>   Use CUFFT: YES 
>   Use CUBLAS: NO
>   
>   NVIDIA GPU arch: 11 12 13 20 21 30 
>   NVIDIA PTX archs: 11
>   12 13 20 21 30 
>  NVIDIA GPU features: 11 12 13 20 20 30 20
>          Python: 
>  Interpreter: NO 
>          Documentation: 
>   Build Documentation: NO 
>   Sphinx: NO 
>  PdfLaTeX compiler: NO 
>   Tests and samples:
>  Tests:
>   YES
>  Performance tests: YES 
>  Examples: NO
>  
>         Install path: C:/opencv/Builds/install
>  cvconfig.h is in: C:/opencv/Builds
>  
>   -----------------------------------------------------------------
>          Configuring done
>   Generating done

Now if i Build the solution the build fails and it gives me an error. These are a few errors from a lot of them:

> Error 8 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   '....\lib\Debug\opencv_gpu242d.lib' opencv_stitching
>   Error 9
>   fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   '....\lib\Debug\opencv_gpu242d.lib' opencv_videostab
>  Error 10
>   fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   '....\lib\Debug\opencv_gpu242d.lib' opencv_test_stitching
>   Error
>   13 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   '....\lib\Debug\opencv_gpu242d.lib' opencv_perf_stitching

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance,
Shilpa

Comment: I would like to add that precompiled OpenCV binaries have GPU libraries only for Visual Studio 10, also.

Comment: In that case do we need to add the libraries manually for Visual Studio 2008? If so in what path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know what the problem was. I tried installing the same in a different computer and it worked like a charm. So i re installed the OS and it worked!!