# OpenCV w/ CUDA build fail on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, cuda

Trying to build OpenCV 2.4.10 with CUDA (6.5) on VS 2013, but it keeps throwing errors like these:

[image: OpenCV build fail]

I've followed [OpenCV's instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation), and tried this [slightly outdated post](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/03/22/how-to-build-opencv-2-2-with-gpu-cuda-on-windows-7/) with no luck. I understand that the "std has no member max/min" is most likely caused by a missing `#include <alrotighm>`, but there has to be something I didn't do correctly since this is the out-of-the-box OpenCV source.

Also - When I build without the GPU module, everything works fine. (Something wonky with CUDA toolkit..?)

It seems [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785697/install-opencv-2-4-2-with-cuda-on-visual-studio-9-2008-errors-in-build) 2 years ago had the same problem, but I can't reinstall the OS. The best I could try was moving all source files to another drive and give all the write/read permissions to everybody. Still the same errors. Please help, thanks!

Comment: ***but there has to be something I didn't do correctly since this is the out-of-the-box OpenCV source.*** My guess is that the developers probably are not using Visual Studio 2013 with cuda enabled. Older versions of Visual Studio and gcc did not need this include.

Comment: ***It seems this SO question 2 years ago had the same problem,*** To me this is a different issue.

Comment: Open the file `NCV.cu` in the directory `/modules/gpu/src/nvidia/core` of opencv source code. `#include<algorithm>` at the top of this source file. Recompile opencv.

Comment: Well apparently that was it, thanks guys!